# Selecting Rows and removing duplicates based on some fields based on two fields and limit to Top Ten?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Having this table:

```
    Row    Athlete    Event     Mark           Meet
    1        1       3           10              A
    2        2       2           5               A
    3        3       3           3               A
    4        4       4           7               A
    5        2       2           4               A
    6        3       2           5               B
    7        1       1           10              C
```

How can I select all rows but remove duplicate rows with have the athlete in the same event (Fields Athlete and Event), and pick the lowest (or highest Mark for that athlete), I would also like to limit each event to top 10 athletes (not shown in results)

Expected Output (choosing highest mark), (row 5 is removed)

```
    Row    Athlete    Event     Mark           Meet
    1        1       3           10              A
    2        2       2           5               A
    3        3       3           3               A
    4        4       4           7               A
    6        3       2           5               B
    7        1       1           10              C
```

Thanks for the help the query that did what I wanted (minus the top ten) is:

SELECT [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Eventnum, [tblPerformanceData-      FieldBoys].Mark, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Meet, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].CY, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].AthleteID, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].MeetID

FROM [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys] INNER JOIN MaxAthleteByEventBoysField ON ([tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].AthleteID = MaxAthleteByEventBoysField.AthleteID) AND ([tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Mark = MaxAthleteByEventBoysField.MaxOfMark) AND ([tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Eventnum = MaxAthleteByEventBoysField.Eventnum)

GROUP BY [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Eventnum, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Mark, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Meet, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].CY, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].AthleteID, [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].MeetID

ORDER BY [tblPerformanceData-FieldBoys].Mark DESC;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using cascading queries.  Try running a group-by query on the main table that only includes the athlete, event, and mark.  The max or min clause would be applied to the mark depending on the outcome you're looking for.  Use this query as the source for a second query where you link back to the initial table using direct links between the athlete, event, and Mark field.  [what the second query should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqEyM.jpg)

That solves the first part.  I'm not sure how to get the top ten for each event using queries.

Comment: Thanks..the first query worked just fine when I limited the query to the three fields...however, could not get it to work with your linked table and query.

Comment: you built the second query like the picture I attached?  The purpose of the second query is to incorporate the missing columns from query1.

Comment: I built it exactly as attached.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.  It worked as built on my machine (using the data set shown above)

Comment: Thanks iveyb123...after trying your method again it worked..the query is posted in the question at the bottom that finally worked.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  You could solve the top 10 problem by creating a vba function to scan through the data set and rank the scores for each match (e.g. 1-25), then you'd just need to specify in your queries rank <=10.  If you want to pursue this, I can help.

Comment: I ended up just doing the top ten by vba code in the report. That seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't own or have access to MS Access, but I can give you SQL, and hope Access will support some basic syntax.

Option 1: it's easier if `Row` is your primary key but you do not need to return it in the result; in this case you can even get both `MIN` and `MAX` of the `Mark` for the same athlete in the same row using a simple query:

```
SELECT
  Athlete, Event, Meet, MAX(Mark) AS HighestMark, MIN(Mark) AS LowestMark
FROM
  MyTable
GROUP BY
  Athlete, Event, Meet
```

Note: I assumed you also want to group by `Meet`, but if that's not the case, you could remove it from `GROUP BY`, but then its value loses meaning in the result.

Option 2: `Row` is primary key, but you do need to return it - obviously in this case min and max cannot be returned in the same row and the query looks quite different:

```
SELECT
  Row, Athlete, Event, Mark, Meet
FROM
  MyTable m0
WHERE m0.Row IN
  (SELECT MAX(Row)
   FROM MyTable m1
   WHERE
     Athlete = m0.Athlete AND
     Event = m0.Event AND
     Meet = m0.Meet
     Mark = (SELECT MAX(Mark)
             FROM MyTable
             WHERE
               Athlete = m1.Athlete AND
               Event = m1.Event AND
               Meet = m1.Meet)
   GROUP BY
     Athlete, Event, Meet, Mark)
```

Few notes:

- above query returns `MAX(Mark)`; change it to `MIN(Mark)` to return lowest values
- this query could be rewritten with `JOIN`s as well; I'm not sure which method Access likes better (i.e. runs faster)
- it has 2 sub-queries; the top sub-query `MAX(Row)` is there to make sure only 1 row is selected if the same athlete in the same meet and event gets the same Mark; in this case, the greater `Row` is returned
- it is possible to return both `MIN` and `MAX` with one query (as separate rows) at the expense of additional sub-queries, but that you didn't ask for